# Prove that if $1\in \bigcup_{\alpha\in\mathbb{A}}$ $O_{\alpha}$ then {${O_\alpha}$}$_{\alpha\in\mathbb{A}}$ contains a finite sub-cover for $[0,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that {${O_\alpha}$}$_{\alpha\in\mathbb{A}}$ is an open cover for [0,1). Prove that if $1\in \bigcup_{\alpha\in\mathbb{A}}$$O_{\alpha}$ then {${O_\alpha}$}$_{\alpha\in\mathbb{A}}$ contains a finite sub-cover for $[0,1)$.

Proving things with covers and sub-covers is very confusing to me and I never know where to start.

Comment: Can you conclude that this cover is also the cover for [0,1]?

Comment: When you hear of something that has a finite sub-cover the first thing that comes to mind should be a compact set or in your case a closed interval...

Answer (score 2):

Since $\{O_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in \mathbb{A}}$ is an open cover of $[0,1)$ and $1 \in O_\alpha$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{A}$, it readily follows that $\{O_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in \mathbb{A}}$ is actually an open cover for $[0,1]$. Using that $[0,1]$ is compact, the family $\{O_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in \mathbb{A}}$ has a finite sub-cover containing the set $[0,1] \supset [0,1)$.